# Can HTML input contain multiple DB column names, (If data not in column x, check column y)

Tags: php, html, input

I am trying to validate a user login through one login form.
I have 2 user tables

1. Employee
2. Client

I want to be able to have the same display for both users to login.

Can the input field contain the 2 different name fields in order to check the relevant database columns?

```
<li><input id='input1' type='text' name='Employee_Username' name='Client_Username' placeholder=' Username.....' required>
```

Comment: why don't you just add <select>?

Comment: You could just add a select or a radio button with "Employee" and "Client" option and choose what table to authenticate against in your back end based on that?

Comment: No, a single value can not have two different keys.  But you can pass the value twice with different keys.  However, the *real* problems here are: (1) You imply that you're relying on user input for the *column name* in your database, which strongly implies that you have serious security vulnerabilities in your code; and (2) Why do you have two different tables to store users?  Users are a single entity.  **Roles** can be varied, but there should be only one table for the actual users.

Comment: you can make it to verify with id by sayign select ID where name and by the ID you can determine which role the user is and what actions can the user do.

Comment: input should have only one name, you can not assign two names to input field

Comment: Why is the form even relevant here? Ultimately you'll get a user identifier from some http request. To what other value (db column) you compare that, should in **absolutely** no way be dictated by some html structure!

Answer (score 1):

Herewith a select with submit in one form depending on the selection you can call different functions or values in controller.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="type">Choose Type:</label>
  <select name="yourname" id="yourid">
    <option value="employee">Employee</option>
    <option value="client">Client</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
 <li><input id='input1' type='text' name='Employee_Username' name='Client_Username' placeholder=' Username.....' required> 
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```